# How to fix image background in MS Edge Browser in Dark Mode on Android

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

I have a very simple website showing some buttons from the app store. The code for the button is provided by Apple. Website background is always black.

This works everywhere except for the Edge browser on Android in dark mode.

For some reason Edge in dark mode overrides the image background to white making the white text invisible!? This only happens on Android.

How can this be fixed?

Below is the app store button in Android Edge "light mode" and everywhere else including Edge on PC.

[image: App Store Button]

In Android Edge in dark mode it is just a white rectangle!?

This is the code:

```
    <img src="https://tools.applemediaservices.com/api/badges/download-on-the-app-store/black/en-us?size=250x83&amp;releaseDate=1667952000"
                    alt="Download on the App Store"
                    style="border-radius: 13px; width: 90%;">
```

Comment: I have tested some code you provided, it works fine. Here is my test result( ColorOS 13.1 ) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/07lyn.png , could you provide more details about this issue? You can also re-install Edge to check if this issue occur, or check if this issue occur in other mobile devices.

Comment: In that pic the background is white, how come? My website has black background in dark mode... Below is my header info: 
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
 <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

Comment: It seems that I only enabled Dark Mode but did not set and enable "All web pages to be in dark mode". I reproduced your issue, and in this case, I recommend that you to send feedback to relevant team, press `Alt+Shift+I` to edit your report and send it. Thank you for your understanding, it will help improve Edge.

Comment: The issue is on android, there are no alt-shift keys!

Comment: Well, you can find feedback feature in settings in second page. Hope this issue can be resolved soon.